# Displaying divs into the screen optimizing the space

Tags: html, css, angularjs, image, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have div cards like feedly, I want that the behavior be the same.

In this momento I have this:

[image: Current]

I'd want this:

[image: Desired]

My code is this:

```
<div ng-repeat="obj in list" class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <img src="{{obj.image}}" class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <strong class="col-md-12">{{obj.name}}</strong>
        <p class="col-md-12">{{obj.summary}}</p>
        <p class="col-md-12">{{obj.cel}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note: I can't put height fixed.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you had a look at gridStack.js? - http://troolee.github.io/gridstack.js/?ref=jQueryCards.com

Comment: I had a lot of trouble with jquery and angular, even I developed my own "lightbox" with bootstrap for "owl carousel", It took me as a week. Because lightbox with libraries had a lot of trouble.

In this moment I finished to test with this "gridStack.js" and shows me, that doesn't recognize the function ".gridstack()".

I don't want do it with another jquery library :/

Maybe as you seen, I have 4 objects into the div card.

If I put height fixed, how can I do for only the image change the size?